# How to match strings in file names and rename file according to string?

Tags: linux, bash, rename

I have many files with matching strings in file names.

```
foostring.bar
barstring.bar
fuustring.bar
aha_foostring.abc
meh_barstring.abc
lol_fuustring.abc
...
```

I need to find the bar and abc files with matching strings, and rename the *.bar-files basename to the look like the *.abc-files. In other words, add a string prefix.

The result I'm looking for should look like this:

```
aha_foostring.bar
meh_barstring.bar
lol_fuustring.bar
aha_foostring.abc
meh_barstring.abc
lol_fuustring.abc
...
```

**Clarification Edit**: The strings in the *.abc-files are always situated after the last underscore `_` and before the dot `.` The string only contains letters and numbers. The prefix can contain any number of characters, and any type of character, including `_` and `.` This means I also need to take the below example into consideration.

```
dindongstring.bar
w_h.a.t_e_v_e.r_dingdongstring.abc
```

I've been experimenting with find, prefix and basename, but I need help and advice here.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with something like this:
(I am sure there are more elegant ways to do it (awk/sed))

```
#!/bin/bash

for filename in *.abc
do
    prefix=${filename%_*}
    searchstring=${filename%.abc}
    searchstring=${searchstring#*_}
    if [[ -f "$searchstring.bar" ]]
    then
        mv "${searchstring}.bar" "${prefix}_${searchstring}.bar"
    fi
done
# show the result
ls -al
```

---

Apologies for adding this in your answer but since I've deleted my answer and you answer is closest to what OP needs. (I dont mind... I care about solutions =)

**EDIT:** Probably this is what OP wants:

```
for f in *.abc; do
   prefix=${f%_*}
   bar=${f%.abc}
   bar="${bar##*_}.bar"
   [[ -f "$bar" ]] && mv "$bar" "${prefix}_${bar}"
done
```

Comment: Since I work with hundreds of files with all kinds of prefixes, this works. Only exception is when prefixes contain the "_" character

Comment: @user1253164 If it works for you, why don't you accept the answer?

Comment: Full hit according to my clarification regarding `_` and `.`  Thanks to you both. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to try the following "magick":

```
$ join -j 2 <(ls -1 . | sed -n '/\.bar/s/^\(.*\)\(\.[^.]\+\)$/\1\2\t\1/p' | sort -k2) <(ls -1 . | sed -n '/\.abc/s/^\(.\+_\)\?\([a-zA-Z0-9]\+\)\(\.[^.]\+\)$/\1\2\3\t\2\t\1/p' | sort -k2) | awk '{print $2 " " $4}' | while read FILE PREFIX; do echo mv -v "$FILE" "$PREFIX$FILE"; done
mv -v barstring.bar meh_barstring.bar
mv -v dingdongstring.bar w_h.a.t_e_v_e.r_dingdongstring.bar
mv -v foostring.bar aha_foostring.bar
mv -v fuustring.bar lol_fuustring.bar
```

If it will show expected commands then remove `echo` before `mv` and run again to do the changes.

Note also that there I use `ls -1 .` command to show files of the current directory, probably you'll need to change directory or run command in directory with files.

Little explanation:

The idea behind that code is to create pairs of filename-common part for .bar and .abc files:

```
$ ls -1 . | sed -n '/\.bar/s/^\(.*\)\(\.[^.]\+\)$/\1\2\t\1/p' | sort -k2
barstring.bar   barstring
dingdongstring.bar  dingdongstring
foostring.bar   foostring
fuustring.bar   fuustring
$ ls -1 . | sed -n '/\.abc/s/^\(.\+_\)\?\([a-zA-Z0-9]\+\)\(\.[^.]\+\)$/\1\2\3\t\2\t\1/p' | sort -k2
meh_barstring.abc   barstring   meh_
w_h.a.t_e_v_e.r_dingdongstring.abc  dingdongstring  w_h.a.t_e_v_e.r_
aha_foostring.abc   foostring   aha_
lol_fuustring.abc   fuustring   lol_
```

As you can see there the 2nd field is common part. After that we join these lists together by common part and leave only .abc filename and prefix:

```
$ join -j 2 <(ls -1 . | sed -n '/\.bar/s/^\(.*\)\(\.[^.]\+\)$/\1\2\t\1/p' | sort -k2) <(ls -1 . | sed -n '/\.abc/s/^\(.\+_\)\?\([a-zA-Z0-9]\+\)\(\.[^.]\+\)$/\1\2\3\t\2\t\1/p' | sort -k2) | awk '{print $2 " " $4}'
```

barstring.bar meh_
dingdongstring.bar w_h.a.t_e_v_e.r_
foostring.bar aha_
fuustring.bar lol_

And final step is to rename files by adding appropriate prefix to them.

Comment: Getting **sed: can't read filenames: No such file...**. Thanks for the elaboration and the oneliner

Comment: I supposed that `filesnames` is a file with file names. I've updated my one-liner that gets file names from current directory and also takes into account names like `w_h.a.t_e_v_e.r_dingdongstring.abc`